# Highchart Graph Issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts to display data which I get from the database. I push data to series like this:

```
var seriesDemo = {x: data[i]["fld_DateTime"], y:data[i]["fld_ConsumptionValue"] * 1, deviceType: data[i]["fld_DivisionId"]};
series[newSeriesIndex]["data"].push(seriesDemo);

x_axis = { categories: ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"] };


var info = {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            renderTo: divInfo,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: title,
            x: -20
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: "",
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: x_axis,
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            pointFormatter: function() {                    
                    return this.series.name + ' : <b>' + this.y + '</b> ' + UNIT_TYPE[this.deviceType] + '<br/>' +
                    localize("em_consumption_comparison_report_price") + ' : <b>' + (this.y * UNIT_PRICE_ARRAY[this.deviceType]).toFixed(2) + '</b> ' + MONEY_UNIT_ARRAY[this.deviceType] + '<br/><br/>';
              },

            //xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        legend: {
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: series
    };
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(info);
```

There isn't any error/warnings in the console, but no graph is displayed which can be seen in the below photo
[image]

There's data and format seems good. 
My Data Array's output (which I can see from console is like this):

```
0:{x: "  00:00", y: 328.52, deviceType: 0}
1:{x: "  01:00", y: 640.04, deviceType: 0}
2:{x: "  02:00", y: 736.9,  deviceType: 0}
3:{x: "  03:00", y: 621.68, deviceType: 0}
4:{x: "  04:00", y: 565.82, deviceType: 0}
5:{x: "  05:00", y: 170.12, deviceType: 0}
 ....................................
 ....................................
23:{x: "  23:00", y: 196.12, deviceType: 0}
```

Anyone can see the problem here?

Comment: If you could fiddle with sample data it would help....

Comment: I think you need to push `series` data into `yAxis` object. Otherwise it all of your points are lying on the y = 0 line.

Comment: If your data is sorted and you have set xAxis.categories array, get rid of x parameter from series' points. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0r09kszd/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data's `x` properties all have leading spaces, so Highcharts cannot associate them with the values in your `categories` array.

Either remove the leading spaces or map the `x` properties to the corresponding index of your `categories` array (so that `x: "00:00"` would be `x: 0`, `x: "01:00"` would be `x: 1`, and so on).

Comment: ıt's a category based series.
x_axis = { categories: ["00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"] };

Comment: I realize that. What I'm saying is that `"01:00" !== "  01:00"`, so either fix your leading whitespace or use the index position.